# base change of an equivalence relation of fppf sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, topos-theory

Let $S$ be a scheme, $R,U$ be $S$-schemes and $s,t : R \to U \times_S U$ be an equivalence relation i.e. it's a monomorphisme such that for every $S$-scheme $T$, $R(T) \to U(T) \times U(T)$ is and equivalence relation in the usual sense.

We denote by $Q$ the $fppf$ sheaf associated to the presheaf
$$T \mapsto U(T)/\sim_{R(T)}
$$

The arrow $\pi : U \to Q$ is the coequalizer, in the category of $fppf$ sheaves, of the maps $s,t : R \to U$ seen as maps of $fppf$ sheaves. Note that as such it is an epimorphism.

Let $\pi : Q' \to Q$ be any morphism. We define $R' = R \times_Q Q'$ and $U' = U\times_Q Q'$. I want to show that $Q'$ is the coequalizer of the maps $(s',t') : R' \to U' \times_{R'} U'$. **So what I want to show is that the formation of quotients of equivalence relations commutes with base change in the category of $fppf$ sheaves**

I know that $(s,t) : R \to U \times_Q R$ is an isomorphism of $fppf$ sheaves (it isn't absolutely obvious but it's not very hard to see). This implies very easily that $R' \cong U' \times_{Q'} U'$. So the question becomes to show it that $U' \to Q$ is the equalizer of $p_1,p_2 : U' \times_{Q'} U' \to U'$.

My idea was to show that $U' \to Q$ is an epimorphism because I've already shown that this implies the result, but I haven't been able to show this.

So another (and maybe clearer) question would be : **in the category of $fppf$ sheaves, are epimorphisms stable by base change ?** Let me remind you that a morphism $\alpha : F \to G$ of $fppf$ sheaves (on the category of $S$-schemes) is an epimorphism if for every $S$-scheme $T$ and for every section $s \in G(T)$ there exists and $fppf$ covering $\{T_i \to T\}_{i \in I}$ such that $s_{|T_i}$ is in the image of $F(T_i) \to G(T_i)$.

It is certainly true in the category of sets that epimorphisms are stable by base change so I imagine the result would be true for epimorphisms of sheaves over any site.

Anyway, if it is not the case, then how can one show that $Q'$ is the co-equalizer of $(s',t')$ ?

Comment: There's nothing special about fppf sheaves here. These are standard facts about all sheaf toposes, codified in Giraud's axioms. A cheap proof is to observe that the statements in question are true in $\mathbf{Set}$ and sheafification preserves the truth of these statements.

Comment: Hey, thanks. That's what I thought but I couldn't make the argument work. I'll give it another try.

Comment: Here is I guess how the argument would go : Let C be a site $p : F \to G$ an epimorphism of sheaves and $g : Q \to G$ a morphism of sheaves. We want to show that $p_Q : F \times_G Q \to Q$ is an epimorphism. Let's write $I$ for the image presheaf of $p_Q$. What we want to show is that $I^\# = Q$. But I really don't see how that would work. Let $T \in C$ if we knew that there was a cover $\{T_i \to T\}$ such that $(p_q)_{|T_i}$ is surjective for all i then we would be done by the case of sets. But this isn't true I think. Would you mind maybe flesh out a little bit how the argument would go ?

Comment: It is true that epimorphisms are preserved by base change, but the technique I described is not directly applicable. Try instead to show that the coequaliser of a given pair of morphisms is preserved by base change (in the appropriate sense).

Comment: Ah yes,thanks a lot. Here is how the argument would go if someone ever reads this. let $u,v : F \to G$ be morphisms of sheaves and $G \to Q$ be a co-equalizer. Now we want to show that for a morphism $Q' \to Q$, $G' \to Q'$ coequalizes $u',v'$. For every $T \in C$ we now that $G'(T) \to Q'(T)$ coequalize $u',v' : F(T) \to G(T)$ because it is easy to see that coequalizer are stable by base change in the category of sets. That means that $G' \to Q'$ is a coequalizer in the category of presheaves and now passing to the sheafification it implies that it also the case in the category of sheaves.

Comment: In fact this implies that epimorphisms are stable by base change because in a topos epimorphisms are effective (i.e; they are always co-equalizers).

Comment: There's a minor subtlety in that $G \to Q$ needs to be the coequaliser in the category of presheaves, not sheaves. But otherwise that's the idea.

Comment: Ah  you're right that's a problem ! Does this work  : let $P$ be the co-equalizer in the category of presheaves. Then $P^\# = Q$. Then by the same argument as before $P'$ is the co-equalizer of $(s',t')$ in the category of presheaves and because (i need to check this) $P'^\# = Q'$ this implies the result ? Thanks a lot for your help Zhen Lin !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose given a parallel pair $X \rightrightarrows Y$ in $\mathbf{Sh}$. Let $Y \to \tilde{Z}$ be the coequaliser in $\mathbf{Psh}$ and let $Z$ be the sheaf associated with $\tilde{Z}$; then $Y \to Z$ is the coequaliser in $\mathbf{Sh}$. Now, consider a morphism $Z' \to Z$ and define $X' = Z' \times_Z X$, $Y' = Z' \times_Z Y$, and $\tilde{Z}' = Z' \times_Z \tilde{Z}$; note that we get a parallel pair $X' \rightrightarrows Y'$ in $\mathbf{Sh}$. Since coequalisers in $\mathbf{Set}$ are preserved by base change, $\tilde{Z}'$ is the coequaliser of $X' \rightrightarrows Y'$. Moreover, the associated sheaf functor preserves finite limits and all colimits, so $Z'$ is the sheaf associated with $\tilde{Z}'$ and is the coequaliser of $X' \rightrightarrows Y'$. Hence coequalisers are preserved by base change in $\mathbf{Sh}$.

(It may be helpful to draw some diagrams.)

Comment: Great ! thank you very much.